# Building a JavaScript request through Ruby

Tags: javascript, ruby, mechanize

I'm sorry if the title is confusing.

I'm trying to scrape my job's website to updates on my schedule. I'm using Ruby with Mechanize. I've successfully logged into my job's website, though, once logged in, all of the links going forward are JavaScript links, which Mechanize doesn't play well with.

After doing some research, I saw some suggestions for similar problems; Instead of clicking the link, I can emulate the request the link is making, though I'm not sure at all how I could do this.

The code behind the link is:

```
<a href="JavaScript:document.getElementById('schedForm').submit()">My Work Schedule </a>
```

How might I tackle this in Ruby? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the link is clicked, it submits a form.
To accomplish the same thing with mechanize:

```
page.form(:id => 'schedForm').submit
```

Comment: Can't believe it was that simple. Thank you so much. I was about to make this project many times harder.

Comment: Yes there's usually a simple solution. Giving up and switching to watir is almost always a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

As far I know, Mechanize can't make JavaScript calls. If you need to interact with JavaScript, I would recommend [Watir](http://watir.com/).

Comment: Mechanize can call a URL that JavaScript would, but it can't interpret JavaScript. Watir can't either, but the browser that Watir is controlling can, and Watir can ask the browser what its state is before and afterwards.

Comment: You're absolutely correct, I didn't articulate my answer properly.